# Clone Iterator FileUtils

Tags: java, iterator, fileutils

Good Morning in my timezone.

I have the following code:

```
Iterator<File> files = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directoryPath), new String[]{"java"}, true);

        for(String file : ws){
            while(files.hasNext()){
                current = files.next();
                if(!current.isDirectory()){
                    if(current.getName().matches(file+".*ServiceProxy.*")){
        //I need to start the cycle again from the beginning to search in each
    //file for the ServiceProxy string
    //Something like this
            // cloneFiles = files.clone();
         //while(cloneFiles.hasNext()){
              file = files.next();
              //search inside the file code
         }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

I want to clone the Iterator because this action is very expensive in terms of time

```
FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directoryPath), new String[]{"java"}, true);
```

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterable`:

```
Iterable<File> filesIterable = new Iterable<>(){
    public Iterator<File> iterator() {
        return FileUtils.iterateFiles(...);
    }
};

...

for (File file : filesIterable) {
    ...
}

// ... and you may reuse it over and over. 
// For each cycle declaration there will be a new `Iterator` created.

for (File file : filesIterable) {
    ...
}
```

It works like this:

1. `for-each` loop asks `filesIterable` to create a new `Iterator`
2. `filesIterable` calls `iterator()`
3. `FileUtils.iterateFiles` creates a new `Iterator`

Comment: But if i use the filesIterable object do not the FilesUtils.iterateFiles will be change either ?
Do not the filesIterable object uses the reference for the FilesUtils.iterateFiles object ?

Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: The problem with that aproach is that it is always calling in my case the  FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(directoryPath), new String[]{"java"}, true); , and that is what i want to avoid because is a very expensive operation, that is why i want to clone the Iterator that this function returns
Thanks for the answer i your time

Comment: Ah, yeah, you're right I've recalled this weirdness in `FileUtils`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(directoryPath), 
    new String[]{"java"}, true);
```

to create a collection of files and then reuse it for further iterating. This way it won't scan your root folder each time you want to iterate over files.